# Set textbox and button to 100% width

Tags: html

This is my code:

```
<!--Tracking number input box.-->
<input type="text" id="YQNum" maxlength="50"/>
<!--The button is used to call script method.-->
<input type="button" value="TRACK" onclick="doTrack()"/>
<!--Container to display the tracking result.-->
<div id="YQContainer"></div>

<!--Script code can be put in the bottom of the page, wait until the page is loaded then execute.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.17track.net/externalcall.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doTrack() {
    var num = document.getElementById("YQNum").value;
    if(num===""){
        alert("Enter your number."); 
        return;
    }
    YQV5.trackSingle({
        //Required, Specify the container ID of the carrier content.
        YQ_ContainerId:"YQContainer",
        //Optional, specify tracking result height, max height 800px, default is 560px.
        YQ_Height:560,
        //Optional, select carrier, default to auto identify.
        YQ_Fc:"0",
        //Optional, specify UI language, default language is automatically detected based on the browser settings.
        YQ_Lang:"en",
        //Required, specify the number needed to be tracked.
        YQ_Num:num
    });
}
</script>
```

I've tried to set textbox and button to 100% width with `width:100%` and `width:"100%`, but it did not work.

```
<input type="text" id="YQNum" maxlength="50" width="100%">
<input type="button" value="TRACK" onclick="doTrack()" width="100%">
```

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is some lack of clarity in the question. But is this what you are looking for?

```html
<input type="text" id="YQNum" maxlength="50" style="width:100%;"/>

<input type="button" value="TRACK" onclick="doTrack()" style="width:100%;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply <3.

Sorry for my bad explanation. Basically I want the textbox and button responsive

Comment: That's ok. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)